# When does $A^TAX = A^TB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

The original question is a true-or-false question: **Assume $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $m\times p$ matrix. If $X$ is an $n\times p$ unkwown matrix, then the system $A^TAX = A^TB$ always has a solution.**

To my knowledge, for $A^TAX$ to always have a solution, $A^TA$ must be invertible. For it to be invertible, $A$ must have full column rank. However, it is not specified in the question, so I would assume it is false. However, **the answer is true**. Am I not getting something here? Thanks for any help!

**Edit:** This is the suggested answer given in the question:
Let $X$ = [$X_1$ $X_2$... $X_p$], $B$ = [$b_1$ $b_2$... $b_p$]

$A^TAX = A^TB$ $\Leftarrow$$\Rightarrow$ [$A^TX_1$ $A^TX_2$... $A^TX_p$] = [$A^Tb_1$ $A^Tb_2$... $A^Tb_p$]

Because normal equation $A^TAX_i = A^Tb_i$ must have a solution for all i = 1, 2, ..., p

So $A^TAX = A^TB$ must have a solution

Comment: $A^TAX = A^TB$ (often referred to as the normal equations) usually appears in the context of least squares problems, so it is possible that they are saying a solution to the least squares problem always exists (which is true).

Comment: Part of the distinction comes from the existence/uniqueness divide - solutions to $Ax=b$ can exist when $A$ is not invertible, but they won't generally be unique.

Comment: "$A^TA$ must be invertible" isn't necessarily true. Think of $B=AV$ for some $V$, then $X=V$ is always a solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Correct me if I'm wrong since I'm still a beginner, but for an equation like $Ax = b$, in the case that matrix $A$ is square, were to always have a solution, A must be invertible(full row rank in the case of square matrix implies invertibility). Then $A^TA$ is also a square matrix, but $A^TA$ is only invertible when $A$ has full column rank. So I'm still not getting why $A^TAX = A^TB$ always has a solution.

Comment: @TonyTarng: not at all. For any invertible or non-invertible matrix $A$, $AX=AV$ has the solution $X=V$. Even $0X=0$ has a solution (actually many of them).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have just learnt the concepts not too long ago on an MIT OCW course 18.06 on linear algebra,  and the professor states that in order for the equation $Ax = b$ to always have a solution for every b, $A$ must be of full row rank. Perhaps it is because he is limiting the right hand side of the equation to only contain vectors as oppose to matrix? But $A^Tb$ (NOT B) is a vector as well. This is the link to the Youtube video for reference (around 36:10): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q1q7s1jTzU&index=8&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D

Comment: I have also included the suggested answer in the original post.

Comment: @TonyTarng: do you maintain that $0X=0$ has no solutions ?

Comment: Well, yes it does. But what I meant is that for any $b$, there exists a solution to $Ax = b$ iff A has full column rank?

Comment: You are not in the "any $b$" situation. Your $b$ is $A^TB$.

Comment: Yes, I know. But if you look at the suggested answer I have newly added under the original post, the RHS of the normal equation is of the form $A^Tb$, which is a vector. I suppose my question becomes why does least squares method always produce a solution, even if $A^TA$ is not invertible. I have just understand that the case when $A^TA$ is not invertible, then the solution to $A^TAx = A^Tb$ is not unique.

Answer (score 3):

We consider the case $p=1$ as below.

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and let $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and define 
$W=\{Ax:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$. 
Then it is well-known that there exists an unique vector in $W$, say $Ax_0$ where $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $b-Ax_0\in W^\perp$. Thus
$$0=\left\langle Ax,Ax_0-b\right\rangle
=\left\langle x,A^T(Ax_0-b)\right\rangle
=\left\langle x,A^TAx_0-A^Tb\right\rangle, \tag{1}$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If taking $x=A^TAx_0-A^Tb$ into equation $(1)$,
we can get 
$$A^TAx_0-A^Tb={\it 0}\quad\mbox{or}\quad A^TAx_0=A^Tb.$$
Therefore the system $A^TAx=A^Tb$ always has a solution, and this can be easily extended to the case $p>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=1$. What you want to find is $x$ such that $A^TAx=A^Tb$, that is,
$$
A^T(Ax-b)=0
$$
Now it is known that $\mathbb{R}^m=C(A)\oplus N(A^T)$ (explicitly, that $N(A^T)$, the null space of $A^T$ is a complement of the column space $C(A)$ of $A$). Then $b=Au+v$, for some $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A^Tv=0$. Choosing $x=u$ gives the required solution.

For the general case, write $B=[b_1\ b_2\ \dots\ b_p]$ and $X=[x_1\ x_2\ \dots\ x_p]$ and solve separately the $p$ systems $A^TAx_i=A^Tb_i$.

---

Proof of the claim. If $y\in C(A)\cap N(A^T)$, then $y=Az$ for some $z$ and $0=A^Ty=A^TAz$, so $0=z^TA^TAz=(Az)^T(Az)=y^Ty$, so $y=0$. Thus the two spaces are independent. Further,
$$
\dim N(A^T)=m-\operatorname{rank}A^T=m-\operatorname{rank} A
$$
so
$$
\dim C(A)\oplus N(A^T)=
\operatorname{rank}A+(m-\operatorname{rank}A)=m
$$
and so $C(A)\oplus N(A^T)=\mathbb{R}^m$.